# How to find the element by classname

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a loop to check all the elements with a class selector.

I have

html

```
<div class='label'>aaaa</div>
<div class='label'>bbbb</div>
<div class='label'>cccc</div>
<div class='label'>dddd</div>

 var pre=$('.label')

    pre.each(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    })
```

but it doens't show the element (aaaa,bbbb..etc).

How do I do this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pre = $('.label');

pre.each(function(i, el){
    console.log( el );
    // OR
    console.log( this ); // will give you the element

    // suppose to get text
    console.log( $(el).text() ); // or $(this).text()
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WYAS4/2/)***

First argument of `.each()` is `index` and second argument is `value` *(here your target element)*.

Read more about ***[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each)***.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `console.log(el.text());`?

Comment: No because you want the element itself not necessarily the text therein

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Yes. But in this case it would be directly readable in the console :)

Answer (score 1):

For answering's sake, the `.each` method in jQuery passes two values (amongst context) when it's called:

```
.each(function(index,value){
});
```

So my providing only `e` in your each function you're only asking for the index argument. You'd need to supply two arguments to get the actual element or value.

However, when iterating over elements the context of the interative function is also passed the element. So:

```
$('.label').each(function(index,element){
  // element == this
});
```

So if you don't want to supply the second argument you can just refer to `this` within the function.